# 3ds max Rendered Image - Green lines on edges

Tags: animation, 3dsmax, autodesk

I'm trying to texture a scene on Autodesk 3ds max, what I'm doing:

- Select an object and add Unwrap UVW modifier
- Select all faces and Open UV Editor
- Flatten Mapping and Render UVW Template
- Save the template as .jpeg and open it on Photoshop
- Add the texture/images and save it as .psd
- I add the .psd file on the map editor and on UV editor

The problem is that in the rendered image I get green lines on the edges for some reason.

[image]

UV Template:
[image]

Is there any way to fix it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your textures flush with the edges of the template bounds? I haven't used 3ds max before, but I wonder if your textures aren't completely filling the regions of the template that are mapped onto the object. Or perhaps there's some "render edges" setting that needs to be turned off?

Comment: I haven't even changed the UV template... I've just deleted the faces using the magic wand tool and then I added the texture. But the green lines are still there (even in the UV template)

Comment: you can see the uv template above (just added it)

Comment: Then that's your problem right there.

Comment: Should I just delete the green lines from the UV template then?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tall, you have the green lines because those mark the edges of the template, but they aren't supposed to be included in the final template. Since you're using Photoshop, you could use magic wand to select the faces and then expand each selection by a pixel on each side (assuming the green lines are each one pixel wide) and delete, then drop in your face textures (making sure the textures are the right size for the regions you're placing them in, of course)).

A more accurate method, as JPEG files can have artifacts that make region selection tricky sometimes, would be to use multiple layers in your PSD file and place the textured faces exactly on top of the green-outlined regions in different layers, then merge all the layers together (unless 3DS Max supports multilayer PSDs, in which case you wouldn't need to do that unless you wanted to save space, in which case you'd want to export as a more compact image type anyway).

A third method would be to use textures for each face that are slightly larger than the bounds and just place them approximately over the face positions to cover up the green; this would avoid having to be exact, but it would also mean that you'd end up with discontinuities on the edges as adjacent textures would not perfectly match each other.